# Matlab interpolation between structured grid and arbitrary points (unstructured grids)

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a data, which is based on 2D structured mesh of `meshgrid` format. Further, I have clouds of points on a plane (2D unstructured grid), on which I would like to interpolate the information from the structured mesh.

I tried the option `interp2`, which however requires the second mesh to be in `meshgrid` format. This is not my case. I also note there is `scatteredInterpolant`, which does scattered data interpolation. But the interpolated information does not appear accurate. Can someone suggest high accuracy interpolation schemes for this structured to unstructured grid interpolation scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `griddata`. It gets the data (x, y, v) as **scattered points** and interpolates on the requested points (xq, yq).

```
vq = griddata(x(:), y(:), v(:), xq, yq, 'natural');
```

Note: You should choose the interpolation method (here 'natural' for instance) according to what exactly you want.